# Retrieve all rows of a table with data in adjacent columns while skipping ones that do not?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup, xlookup

I've been struggling to find a way to use index/match in order to return only the rows of a table that have data in corresponding adjacent columns while skipping ones that do not.
I've been successful in grabbing rows that have data in one specific column - such as column 4. But I cant for the life of me figure out a way to nest an OR function or something that would look across multiple columns?

Here is an example of what I've got setup:

Data Table:

| ID | X | Y | Z | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 222 |  | 5 |  |  |
| 333 |  |  |  |  |
| 444 |  |  |  | 8 |
| 555 |  |  | 9 |  |
| 666 | 87 | 1 |  |  |

Here is my current formula:

=INDEX(A1:E6, SMALL(IF((INDEX(A1:E6, , 2)<=9999)  * (INDEX(A1:E6, , 2)>=1), MATCH(ROW(A1:E6), ROW(A1:E6)), ""), ROWS(A1:A1)),COLUMNS(B2))

This outputs:

111

666

Since its only looking in column B.

What i want instead are all of the rows instead of row 3 which is the only row without any data. It doesnt have to be via index/match!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have O365 you can use the filter/byrow/lambda/concat functions:

```
=FILTER(E4:I9,BYROW(F4:I9,LAMBDA(b,CONCAT(b)))<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This works as intended

Answer (score 2):

Using a **Table** with structured references:

In a single cell:

```
=FILTER(
    Table1[ID],
    BYROW(
        DROP(Table1, , 1),
        LAMBDA(arr, OR(arr <> ""))
    )
)
```

[image]